# React - Folder structure

Tags: reactjs

Is it a good practice to put **App.js**, **App.css** and **App.test.js** in to a folder called **app** and put the **app** folder inside **src/components** folder?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on an individual. According to me, things are good as it comes when creating react app :)